# ExCrypto on OTP 24

Tags: dependencies, elixir, elixir-mix

The application is upgraded to run elixir 1.12.2 and uses OTP 24 and I have confirmed these are the versions running.

When running some tests I get the following error:

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function :crypto.block_encrypt/4 is undefined or private, use crypto:crypto_one_time/5, crypto:crypto_one_time_aead/6,7 or crypto:crypto_(dyn_iv)?_init + crypto:crypto_(dyn_iv)?_update + crypto:crypto_final instead
```

Most of the googling I have done suggested upgrading plug_crypto to version 1.2.2, which has been done.

This function block_encrypt/4 is underlying Erlang code and the line which calls block_encrypt/4 in my Elixir code is:

```
ExCrypto.encrypt(content_key, "", content_json)
```

I found a PR for ExCrytpo which is supposed to fix this: https://github.com/ntrepid8/ex_crypto/pull/40

Someone left a comment asking if the code needs to be pushed to hex.pm, and wondering if it's possible this code wasn't released to hex.pm yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it seems that ExCrypto has not published the release containing the changes in that PR to Hex yet. The latest version [on hex](https://hex.pm/packages/ex_crypto) is `0.10.0`, was released on Feb 20, 2019. The PR was merged on May 27, 2021.

As a workaround, you could use the git repository as the source of the dependency, rather than Hex:

```elixir
{:ex_crypto, git: "https://github.com/ntrepid8/ex_crypto.git", branch: "master"}
```

It might be a good idea to pin to the specific commit, rather than the master branch:

```elixir
{:ex_crypto,
 git: "https://github.com/ntrepid8/ex_crypto.git",
 ref: "0915c274503f9fc6d6f5fab8c98467e7414cf8fc"}
```

Another (probably better) option is that you could remove your dependency on ExCrypto by updating your code to use the Erlang `:crypto` library directly.